# Form Email Output styling

Tags: php, html, forms, email, styles

I have created a html form which i inserted into my webpage and have done a php file to send me the details entered into the from via email however,

1. i don't receive a email

and

1. i would like to receive the results with html formatting.

I have looked everywhere to try find a solution but did not find one.

Could someone please help please i am really really stuck.

Thank You

My HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="/form/php/sendresults.php">
<label>First Name:  <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" maxlength="30" />   
   </label>
<label>Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastname" size="30" maxlength="30" />   
   </label>
<textarea name="comments" rows="8" cols="50"  style="margin-left:37px" />
</textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

PHP CODE

```
 <?php
$to = 'info@my.com';
$subject = $firstname;
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>'.$firstname.'</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>'.$firstname.'!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Full Name</th><th>Company Name</th><th>Company Registered Number</th><th>Phone Number</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>'.$lastname.'</td><td>'.$comments.'</td><td>'.$firstname.'</td><td>'.$firstname.'</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mail` function of PHP is really weak. I would recommend you use something like [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) or [mandrill](http://mandrillapp.com/). You can use Mandrill's API ( It's really easy and works like a charm ) . If you're interested in Mandrill's API, you can learn it on codecademy

Comment: thank you however i need this asap :( i have no time to spare just need a simple method to have the output styled in html

Comment: It actually isn't that tough. The lesson on codecademy can be done in a few hours or an hour. It's really simple and I've already done it.

Comment: Thank you ill look into it and for the time being is there anything i can change in my php code to achieve what i want ?

Comment: that's the problem i don't receive email once the form is submitted i use wordpress and its mail client works perfectly with everything else but not my form